# Incremental copy cdc records with dynamic source in Azure ADF

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I have created a pipeline in Azure ADF to copy changed rows from 54 tables in our source db. I have followed the guide from [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-data-capture-feature-portal). And modified it to support dynamic tables.

Im using a lookup to get all active CDC tables and then For each activity to execute the copy on every CDC table and it works good. But When I try to add the Trigger_Start_Time example code in the Azure guide I get this error:

A database operation failed with the following error:

> 'Incorrect syntax near '{'.'
> Incorrect syntax near '{'.
> , SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,State=1.

Here is the example of the code I'm trying to execute:

```sql
@concat('DECLARE @begin_time datetime, @end_time datetime, @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10) ; 
SET @begin_time = ''',pipeline().parameters.TriggerStartTime,''';
SET @end_time = ''',pipeline().parameters.TriggerEndTime,''';
SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn(''smallest greater than or equal'', @begin_time);
SET @to_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn(''largest less than or equal'', @end_time);
SELECT count(1) changecount FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_@{item().Table_Name}(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, ''all'')')
```

I use the @{item().Table_Name} to set the table name. It works good if I hard code the table name like: "Customer"

What am I missing, when I use the source parameter in the query?

Comment: Assuming you copied from [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-data-capture-feature-portal#configure-the-tumbling-window-trigger-and-cdc-window-parameters) your attempt is different. Why do you have braces in your code? There are none on that entire page you linked to.

Comment: Hi, the example that Azure have is only for fixed tables. So I have changed it so I can use dynamic tables. So I user @{item().Table_Name} to get the value from the "For each" activity.

Comment: Hi, Can you try separating the item name in the contact() list from the string? same u did as pipeline parameter Ex: @concat('...',item().Table_Name,'...')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When including current item in **concat()** function, use it as `item().Table_Name`.

```
@concat('DECLARE @begin_time datetime, @end_time datetime, @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10) ; 
SET @begin_time = ''',pipeline().parameters.TriggerStartTime,''';
SET @end_time = ''',pipeline().parameters.TriggerEndTime,''';
SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn(''smallest greater than or equal'', @begin_time);
SET @to_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn(''largest less than or equal'', @end_time);
SELECT count(1) changecount FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_',item().Table_Name,'(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, ''all'')')
```

This query in pipeline looks like below,

[image]